# Is there a word for when others find a view or thing pretty/breathtaking but you feel nothing?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

Is there a word or idiom for when a view or object/thing others find breathtaking or pretty makes you feel nothing?

Edit: Ideally an adjective describing the idea of not seeing beauty in something others do, I suppose. It's definitely more of a disconnect than anything else.

Comment: Something you say to them, or they to you, or an adjective describing the situation? Disconnect, indifference, esthetic disagreement?

Answer (score 2):

**"Beauty is in the eye of the beholder"** is a phrase that captures the notion that beauty is subjective and that different people may find different things beautiful. It's often used to "explain" why someone finds something beautiful when you consider it not to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can be **underwhelmed** by something. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/underwhelm) has

> **underwhelm**
> <sub>VERB *humorous*</sub>
>
> Fail to impress or make a positive impact on (someone); disappoint.
>
> **Origin** 1950s suggested by [overwhelm](https://www.lexico.com/definition/overwhelm).

Comment: A good word. and it has the big advantage over long phrases that it has a useful associated adjective "underwhelming" and adverb £underwhelmingly". By echoing "overwhelming", it contrasts implicitly and effectively with those who find the scene overwhelmingly wonderful. I commend this answer to those who read it; it deserves voting up.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a general affliction, then maybe:

***anhedonic***

which is the adjective form of

> anhedonia: lack of pleasure or of the capacity to experience it ([dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/anhedonia))

Answer (score 0):

If you find something to not be as beautiful as others say they do, and what they say is really all you know, then you're finding it to [not be all it's been cracked up to be](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/not-all-something-is-cracked-up-to-be#:%7E:text=If%20you%20say%20that%20something,%5Binformal%5D), so you might describe how you've found its beauty as:

> [exaggerated](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/exaggerated) - adj. - unduly or unrealistically magnified

or less formally:

> [hyped-up](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hyped-up) - adj. - intensively or excessively stimulated or
> exaggerated

Now, whether it actually is or isn't as beautiful as people say or as not beautiful as you find it is totally subjective as [beauty is in the eye of the beholder](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beauty%20is%20in%20the%20eye%20of%20the%20beholder), [different strokes for different folks](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/different-strokes-for-different-folks), [it takes all kinds](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/it-takes-all-sorts-to-make-a-world), etc.

Answer (score 0):

A person finds something to lack beauty while others don't. It means that he doesn't have the capability to understand beauty. The following sentences fits the description of that person:

- He has a low **aesthetic standard**.
- He lacks **aesthetic intelligence**.

Comment: I think both of those terms are somewhat insulting given that beauty is in the eye of the beholder, i.e. it's subjective.

Comment: They can be insulting. The only case I find they are not, would be in a special casual relationship like a friend nitpicking at that person in a humorous way.